# How to use Python to extract and work with data within a Google sheet

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I'm trying to use python to extract information from a Google sheet and then run calculations on the data.

Instead of downloading the Google sheet each day and sorting the data according to client ID and then summing the values against the clients ID for the previous day I'm hoping to create a script or something that will do this for me automatically.

My data is timestamped and each entry is grouped by client name (there could be more then one entry per client per day). I want to be able to sum the amounts for the entries per client per day and return a message if the value exceeds a specific amount.